# "IdleStart" function starts again even after timeout. "Angular Js"

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I am beginner in angular. I am trying to implement timeout. I display a model if user is idle for more than 5 seconds. When I successfully logout on **timeout**. This dialog box keeps on appearing. How can I fix this.

[image]

This is my configurations.

```
     IdleProvider.idle(5); 
     IdleProvider.timeout(30); // after 30 seconds idle, time the user out
     KeepaliveProvider.interval(5*60);
```

These are my events:

```
 $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
      Idle.unwatch();
      $uibModal.close();
    });

    $scope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {    
      Idle.unwatch();
      $scope.SignOut();
      $uibModal.close();
    });

   $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
     $scope.warning = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'warning-dialog.html',
      windowClass: 'modal-danger'
    });
  });
```

**UPDATED**

Code of my view:

```
   **<script type="text/ng-template" id="warning-dialog.html">
          <div class="modal-header">
           <h3>You're Idle. Do Something!!!</h3>
          </div>
          <div idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=5" class="modal-body">
           <uib-progressbar max="5" value="5" animate="false" class="progress-striped active">You'll be logged out in {{countdown}} second(s).</uib-progressbar>
          </div>
        </script>**
```

In this div

```
<div idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=5" class="modal-body">
```

If I remove **idle-countdown="countdown"** then model does not appear again and logs me out but me side bar keeps showing. I cant figure it out.

Side bar contains menus and drop downs but after login out those menu disapperas but this plain side bar keeps on showing just by removing "idle-countdown"

[image]

Comment: can you give us a fiddle or plunker of this...

Comment: Its not possible cause its a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to invoke `Idle.unwatch();` before `signing out`.

Comment: where are you invoking `$uibModal.close()`  ? You would need to close the modal so that it disappears.

Comment: $uibModal.close(); I have also added this after Idle End and Idle timeout. did not worked.

Comment: I have an observation so I have updated my question can u please look at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {     
     $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                                     Idle.unwatch();
                                      $uibModal.close();
                        });
                    }, 100);
       });
```

Try this one.

Comment: Nop it did not work. Instead not model does not close after logout.

Comment: Please share your demo code at parag7ghadge@gmail.com